# Need help to understand how Moq resolved the actual query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

Below is my test case which runs fine.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetCompanies_WhenInvokedWithSearchText_ShouldReturnFilteredCompanies()
    {
        // Arrange
        var context = new Mock<IDataContext>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var companies = new List<Company>
        {
            new Company()
            {
                Address = "London",
                Name = "ABC Inc."
            },
            new Company()
            {
                Address = "Newyork",
                Name = "Toyota"
            },
            new Company()
            {
                Address = "Ealing broadway",
                Name = "Amazon"
            }
        };
        context.Setup(s => s.Query<Company>()).Returns(companies.AsQueryable());
        var repository = new CompanyRepository(context.Object);

        // Act
        var expectedCompanies = repository.GetCompanies("ABC");

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, expectedCompanies.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("London", expectedCompanies.ToList()[0].Address);
    }
```

My repository code is like this:

```
    public ICollection<Company> GetCompanies(string searchText)
    {
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(searchText, "searchText");

        return _dbContext.Query<Company>().Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchText) || c.Address.Contains(searchText)).ToList();
    }
```

I just do not get exactly how Moq happen to apply the filter (where) which is present on the actual method but I did not set up in the test?

My guess is, when test executes mocked object's Query method is called with the filter applied to it already. Is it discovering a where clause is present dynamically using reflection?

Just want to understand it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic :) Take a look to this line

```
context.Setup(s => s.Query<Company>()).Returns(companies.AsQueryable());
```

When method `Query<Company>()` is executed, returns `companies.AsQueryable()`. `Where` is executed over this, so Moq is not guessing anything.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now... I mocked only the Query method, rest remains same. Make sense.